# OpenCV make on Ubuntu with opencv_contrib fails due to opencv_xphoto

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I'm trying to build OpenCV on Ubuntu 15.10 with opencv_contrib (to use the nonfree modules). I did the following:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/myname/Downloads/opencv_contrib-master/modules -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D BUILD_opencv_ximgproc=ON ..
```

but I tried also with

```
BUILD_opencv_ximgproc=OFF
```

CMake goes well but it fails during the make step:

```
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8403: recipe for target 'modules/xphoto/CMakeFiles/opencv_xphoto.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/xphoto/CMakeFiles/opencv_xphoto.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

and then:

```
Makefile:136: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by deleting and re-downloading both opencv and opencv_contrib. Then I built everything again:

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/myname/Downloads/opencv_contrib/modules -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D BUILD_opencv_ximgproc=ON ..
make -j7
sudo make install
```